# Communicating with the stdin via python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running an exe from my python code using subprocess with the following code:

```
if subprocess.call(string, stderr=stdPoller, stdout=stdPoller, 
       stdin=stdPoller, shell=True)==0:
    return True
```

`stdPoller` just polls the stdout and stderr and writes to a log. That's not where the problem is.

When I'm running a certain application I get the following error to the std:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot see if a key has been pressed when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.In.Peek.

and then the process crashes.

I've tried using PIPE for the stdin, calls to communicate etc but can't seem to be able to fix this problem.

Comment: I've got a not very nice workaround. If I use "start /wait" in my command (I'm in windows) the application will run OK in a separate prompt. However I'd much rather have the stdout and stderr being redirected to my GUI.

Comment: I never found a solution to this. Had to download the source and change the application code. Console.KeyAvailable in the C# code was causing the issue.