# Redirecting cmd stdout and stderr back to parent

Tags: windows, cmd

If I create a process from a cmd prompt using the `start` command (opening a new cmd) is it possible to redirect the stdout and stderr from that process back to the calling cmd?

Comment: Is there even a way to intercept a process's output to a file in another process if the name of the file is known?

Comment: Your question is poor - as you don't tell the real details of the processes and so readers can't use their experience to help you.  Details make a difference in the real world.

Comment: I disagree, it's a general question that shouldn't need details. But I'll give you a contrived example here to help clarify for you. Say I have test.bat with echo hello world. I then open another cmd in the same path and type start test.bat. A new cmd is opened and Hello World is outputted. I want the output in the original cmd.

Comment: Your explanation is contrived.  That's a problem.  You want a real solution to a real problem, yet you won't mention the real situation. I'm not sure if you have provided support for anyone on technical issues, but if you have then you will know why that causes 20 question situations and solutions that don't work.

Comment: OK foxidrive thank you for your help.

Comment: The answer to your contrived example is no.  A cmd window can't print stdout and stderr output into previously existing cmd window.  However you can print the data into a file and have the other window detect the file.

Comment: Just seen your reply. See below. Looks like there is not a solution to my problem here.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the output of the STARTed process to appear in the parent command console, then simply use the `START /B` option.

If you want to process the output of your command, then you should use `FOR /F ... in ('someCommand') DO ...` instead.

Comment: No I want to run the process in a child and output in the parent. The reason is because I'm running the process from python's subprocess and it won't run right unless it's in it's own terminal. See here: [Communicating with the stdin via python subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700647/communicating-with-the-stdin-via-python-subprocess)

Answer (score 0):

OK. I have yet to find a straightforward answer to this question. I didn't want to bog down my question with what I thought unnecessary detail but seeing as I'm being criticized for the lack of this I'll expand a bit here.

I want to automate the updating of FWs on our production line, so I've a python app that gets the FWs from ftp and then uses the processors flash tool via python subprocess command to upload it to the board's flash. OK for all but one of the tools.

The one tool seems to have a problem when it's not running in its own terminal, so I provide a start to the subprocess command string which allows it to run OK in its own terminal. However, I need the output from this other terminal for logging reasons.

A possible solution was to log stdout and stderr to file using >> or wintee and then poll this file via a thread in my original app (perhaps a rather convoluted solution to the question). However the tool also has a separate problem where it doesn't like any std redirection, so this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Is it an option to write the whole process in a batch file?  It is very odd for the firmware uploader to care about what kind of cmd process it is running under, unless maybe it is a very old tool and needs to use command.com - I'd check further into this.   command is still available in modern Windows even though it passes the commands to a `cmd.exe` it does allow the old tools to think they are running under command.com

Comment: To be honest. It's just that's there an output dialogue on my python app that all the other tools use and it just looks a bit messy if one tools runs in a prompt. Still be better solution for production staff than having everything running in cmd. I'm going to look into modifying the source http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvflashutils/